# Swift "IDAT written into file" . Consumo alto memoria al salvar una lista de png de uno en uno

Tags: ios, swift, programación-móvil

Tengo una función a la que le paso una lista JSON de nombres de archivos .png que tiene que ir gravando en la SandBox a medida que va leyendo de una URL.
A medida que va gravando los pngs la memoria consumida va creciendo.. hasta que llega un momento que si la lista de pngs que voy gravando es muy grande Cuando ya ha consumido cerca de 1200MB aproximadamente sale un error tal como "IDAT written into file"

La funcion que salva la lista JSON seria esta:

```
class func importAndSaveImages(fromJSON: JSON) {
    let entries = fromJSON.arrayValue
    debugPrint(fromJSON)
    for entry in entries {
        let number = entry["data"]["idImages"].string?.components(separatedBy: "\r").count
        debugPrint(entry["data"]["idImages"])
        for i in 0..<number!{
            let name = entry["data"]["idImages"].string?.components(separatedBy: "\r")[i]
            APIController.saveImages(name: name!)
        }
    }
}
```

La funcion que salva los png

```
class func saveImages(name: String) {
    let rootUrl = URL(string: RequestServices.shared.BaseUrl)!.appendingPathComponent(RequestServices.shared.DirectoriImatges).appendingPathComponent("")
    let imageName = name

    var urlImage = rootUrl.absoluteString + imageName

    urlImage = urlImage + ".png"

    let image = UIImage.imageFromUrlString(urlString: urlImage)

    UIImage.saveImage(image: image, imageName: imageName + ".png")
}
```

La funcion de salvar png en sandbox

```
 class func saveImage (image: UIImage?, imageName: String) -> Void {

    let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
    let logsPath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(self.pathImages())

    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    var isDir : ObjCBool = false
    if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: logsPath!.path, isDirectory:&isDir) {
        if isDir.boolValue {
            // file exists and is a directory
        } else {
            // file exists and is not a directory
        }
    } else {
        // file does not exist
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: logsPath!.path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unable to create directory Images \(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }
    }
    let imagePNG = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)

    do {
        try imagePNG?.write(to:logsPath!.appendingPathComponent(imageName),  options: .atomic )
        print("\(imageName) saved")
        return
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo todo lo estas haciendo en el main thread (hilo principal), el cual según Apple solo debe ser para tu UI, la mejor formar de hacerlo es de forma asíncrona con otros hilos que no sean el main thread.

En objectiveC:

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
// task in other thread.
});

En swift:
let myQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue")

myQueue.async {
        //task in other thread.
}